# Making a lookup case insensitive in a SP List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience, list-form

I have a list column lookup with another list, however I noticed when I create a new item the lookup is case sensitive and very strict (for example Domain (DNS) won't appear if you type DNS or domain, you have to type it exactly as it shows in the other list)

Is there a way to make it case insensitive and more like a search where DNS would still show Domain (DNS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint.

There is no way to change this behavior using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

However, you may try customizing the list form using *Power Apps* which gives you more control over form customizations.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it